# Can't install illuminate/notifications in my Lumen

Tags: php, lumen

I'm having an error to install this package `composer require illuminate/notifications` to my Lumen `5.3.3`. I also tried to update my PHP.

Is there something that I need to add or change?

```sh
$ composer require illuminate/notifications
Using version ^5.4 for illuminate/notifications
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove illuminate/mail v5.3.23
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/mail v5.3.23
    - illuminate/notifications 5.4.x-dev requires illuminate/mail 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[5.4.x-dev].
    - illuminate/notifications v5.4.0 requires illuminate/mail 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[5.4.x-dev].
    - illuminate/notifications v5.4.13 requires illuminate/mail 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[5.4.x-dev].
    - illuminate/notifications v5.4.17 requires illuminate/mail 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[5.4.x-dev].
    - illuminate/notifications v5.4.19 requires illuminate/mail 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[5.4.x-dev].
    - illuminate/notifications v5.4.9 requires illuminate/mail 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[5.4.x-dev].
    - illuminate/notifications 5.5.x-dev requires illuminate/mail 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/mail[5.4.x-dev, v5.3.23].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/mail[5.5.x-dev, v5.3.23].
    - Installation request for illuminate/mail (locked at v5.3.23, required as 5.3.*) -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[v5.3.23].
    - Installation request for illuminate/notifications ^5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/notifications[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.9].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Here is my `composer.json`:

```
{
"name": "laravel/lumen",
"description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.3.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
    "krisanalfa/lumen-dingo-adapter": "^0.0.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
    "illuminate/mail": "5.3.*",
    "illuminate/notifications": "5.3.*",
    "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev",
    "laravelista/lumen-vendor-publish": "^2.0",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.1"

},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "~0.9",
    "flipbox/lumen-generator": "^5.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/",
        "database/"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

*I also tried to intall the packages for lumen 5.3 but still it gives me this error*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you still have Lumen `5.3` installed but you want to install `illuminate/notifications` in version `5.4` which **requires** also Lumen to be version `5.4`.

I would do:

- Upgrade Lumen to `5.4` by setting `"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.4.*",` in your `composer.json`
- After that do a `composer update`
- Then install `composer require illuminate/notifications`

OR:

- `composer require illuminate/notifications:~5.3` .. which installs the package for Lumen 5.3

should work as well.

Comment: Hi @codedge I edited my post from above kindly check it. btw thanks for your response ^^

Comment: @AlyssaAndrea Can you try `composer require illuminate/notifications:~5.3`?

Comment: Glad I could help! I updated my answer with the solution from my comment. Maybe you want to mark the answer as the solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`illuminate/notifications:^5.4` needs `illuminate/mail:5.4.*`. You project is using `illuminate/mail:5.3.*` (from your `composer.json` file). So to install `illuminate/notifications:^5.4`, you need to upgrade your `illuminate/mail`. Do this:

```
composer require "illuminate/mail:^5.4"
```

After that

```
composer require "illuminate/notifications:^5.4"
```

Comment: Hi @Alfa I edited my post from above kindly check it. btw thanks for your response ^^